# Как в приложении Android узнать о том, что в телефонной книге были выполнены какие-то изменения?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет!
Интересует, каким образом можно в своем приложении получить оповещение о том, что в телефонную книгу добавили контакт или удалили/отредактировали? В общем отловить изменения в контактах. Есть какое-то системное оповещение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Системного оповещения никакого нет. Надо повесить `ContentObserver` типа:

```
contentObserver=new MyContentObserver();
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver (People.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);

class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private final static String TAG=MyContentObserver.class.getName();

    public MyContentObserver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.i(TAG, "Bingo! Someone has changed contacts database!");
    }
}
```